# How to convert Github-style Wiki page link to Markdown-style link in Bash script

Tags: bash, github, sed, markdown, wiki

first question for me on Stack Overflow.

I am trying to write a Bash script to convert the kind of Github Wiki links generated for other internal Github Wiki pages into conventional Markdown-style links.

The Github Wiki link strings look like this:

`[[An example of another page]]`

I want to convert it to look like this:

`[An example of another page](An-example-of-another-page.htm)`

Documents have an unknown number of these links and I don't know the content.

Currently I have been playing around with one-line sed solutions given to other problems, like this one:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283471/inserting-text-to-existing-text-within-brackets

... with absolutely no success. I'm not even sure where to start with it.

Thanks.

Comment: EDIT: To clarify, I need to leave normal Markdown links that are part of the same string (e.g. `[link 1](link1.htm)`) as they are. So: `[link 1](link1.htm) and [[link 2]]` becomes `[link 1](link1.htm) and [link 2](link-2.htm)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to HatLess for the answer which I adapted. The snippet below converts Github-style links into Markdown-style links, without the two issues that HatLess's solution had. Specifically this doesn't break pre-existing Markdown-style links and it doesn't replace spaces with hyphens within brackets *unless* part of a link.

```
sed -E 's/\[\[(.[^]]*)]]/&(support\-\1\.htm)/g;:jump s/(]\([^ \)]*)[ ]/\1-/;tjump;s/\[\[/\[/g;s/]]\(/]\(/g' | pandoc -t html
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/\[(.[^]]*)\]/\1/g;s/\[(.[^]]*)]/&(\1)/g;:jump s/(\([^ \)]*)[ ]/\1-/;tjump' input_file
[An example of another page](An-example-of-another-page)
```

`s/\[(.[^]]*)\]/\1/g` - Remove brackets `[]`

`s/\[(.[^]]*)]/&(\1)/g` - Duplicate the content inside brackets `[]`, return the match `&`, then manipulate the match and add parenthesis `(\1)`

`:jump s/(\([^ \)]*)[ ]/\1-/;tjump` - Create a label `jump`, match the empty spaces within the match if it is within parenthesis and replace with `-`

Comment: Thanks. This is a helpful start. The problem with your solution is that it strips out pre-existing Markdown links. So if you have `[link 1](link1.html) and [[link ]]` in one stream it correctly changes the latter into a markdown link but strips formatting from the former: `link 1(link1.htm)` I have clarified this in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash's internal regular expression support to find and replace instances of wiki linked `[[text]]` with `[text](text.htm)`. The pattern you want to use is `\[\[([^\]]*)\]\]`

- `\[` and `\]` - escapes the left and right square brackets so that they aren't interpreted as meta-characters that let you match character classes
- `([^\]]*)` captures all text inside the double brackets until the first right square bracket

From there you can evaluate this regex and use the `$BASH_REMATCH` array to extract and manipulate the text. You'll need to run this multiple times in order to match all instances in the string and then replace the string inline using the `/` and `//` operators.

Here's a sample script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

wiki_string="Now, this is [[a story]] all about how
My life [[got flipped-turned upside down]]
And I'd [[like to take a minute]]
Just [[sit]] right there
I'll [[tell you]] how I [[became the prince]] of a town called Bel-Air"

printf 'Original: %s\n' "$wiki_string"

# find each instance of [[text]] and capture the text inside 
# the square brackets
# if successful, BASH_REMATCH will contain the matched text and the
# captured value inside the parentheses
while [[ "$wiki_string" =~ \[\[([^\]]*)\]\] ]]; do
    # escape the [ and ] characters so we can replace [[text]]
    # with our modified value
    replace_text="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
    replace_text="${replace_text/\[\[/\\[\\[}"
    replace_text="${replace_text/\]\]/\\]\\]}"

    # Get the matched value inside the brackets
    link_text="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

    # store another copy of the text with the spaces replaced
    # with dashes and appending .htm
    link_target="${link_text// /-}.htm"

    # Finally, replace the matched [[text]] with [text](text.htm)
    wiki_string="${wiki_string//$replace_text/[$link_text]($link_target)}"
done

printf '\nUpdated: %s\n' "$wiki_string"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its very useful. For now I am hoping Hatless's `sed` answer can come through as it better fits the terse script I currently have. However I will come back to yours and study it as there's a lot in there I didn't know could be done.